# Laravel 5.1 - How to use Model in Global function file

Tags: php, laravel, global, laravel-5.1

I created a `common.php` for my all the global function. When I run my first function {{Common::test()}}

It's working fine But I can not use model in it.

```
namespace App\library;
{
    class Common {

            public static function test()
            {
                echo "Yes";
                return "This comes from Common File";
            }
            public static function getCmsBlocks()
            {
                $model = Modelname::all();
                if($model){
                    echo "asdad";
                }else
                {
                    echo "sadasd";
                }
            }

    }
}
```

I don't get my output when I run {{Common::getCmsBlocks()}}

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Knowing that would help

Comment: Yes, I got a fatal error like Class 'App\library\Modelname' not found

Comment: Ok, so see the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model is in different namespace than **App\library** you will need to prefix the model class name with its namespace, otherwise PHP will try to load **App\library\Modelname** which might not be what you need.

Replace

```
$model = Modelname::all();
```

with

```
$model = \Your\Model\Namespace\Modelname::all();
```

If you use your **Modelname** class in multiple place in declared namespace, you can import/alias that using **use** statement so that you can refer to that class by classname in your code:

```
namespace App\library;
use Your\Model\Namespace\Modelname;
{
  class Common {
    public static function getCmsBlocks()
    {
      $model = Modelname::all(); //this will work now
    }
  }
}
```

There is no way to define global **use** to bused by all namespaces in your file, as **use** always refers to the namespace being declared.

Comment: Thank you so much It's working fine but each and every time i need to declare a namespace in my common.php ?                                                                         it's not possible like we declare a model in a global file and common.php access it's automatic ?

Comment: It is possible to declare it once per namespace you're declaring but that's all - I'll update the answer in a moment. There is no way to declare a "use" globally as it ALWAYS refers to namespace being defined.

Comment: Great so it means if i have 20+ model so i need to declare all the model in my common.php file once right ?

Comment: It will be a lot of work, bu what you are trying - some common class to do manipulate 20 models - is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

As above the answer is perfect but just a few addition if you don't want to include namespace everytime on at start of each file

Use this :

```
\App\ModelName::all();
\App\ModelName1::update(item);
\App\ModelName2::find(1);
```

give path like above and there will be no need to use namespace everytime .

**Note**: above is path to model which is inside App directory . So change accordingly if you are keeping them at separate place .

Comment: You are Right But it's work for only one model. How can i define all model in my common.php file